# How to dynamically generate combination of ASP.NET user controls?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have several user controls, let's say `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. Based on some random input, I need to generate a combination of these. For e.g. if input is `2a3d1a2c` I need to show two of the A's, 3 D's after that, an A again, etc.

I will also need to stabilize clientid's in order for them to work correctly. Because each of these controls use their own `ClientID` property to gather the inputs on themselves. For e.g. user control A internally generates an input named `this.ClientID + "$input1"`, and gathers its input from request like `Request[this.ClientID + "$input1"]`. Since there can be more than one A, each A needs to have the same `(unique) ClientID` after postback in order to get correct inputs from request.

Comment: I'm confused about the problem. By design the control tree must be the same on PostBack as when the page was rendered. Is there a reason why you cannot simply create the controls in order in Page.Init each time? The framework-generated ClientID will be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add controls dynamically, you can use a panel as a place holder, say

```
<asp:Panel ID="ControlPlaceholder" runat="server" />
```

Then, on the server side, you can add objects to it like so:

```
int controlCount = 0;

...

TextBox newTextBox = TextBox();
newTextBox.ID = "ctl_" + controlCount++;
ControlPlaceholder.Controls.Add(newTextBox);
```

If you add the controls to it during your Page_Load event and use a consistent method of generating the controls' IDs (such as a the simple count above) then any viewstate or event bindings will be re-bound to the right object on a postback.

Comment: If matters, it comes from a property of a class that is generated by deserializing a file (: I'll try your solution to see if it helps.